# python dictionary - merge two dictionary and append key values if they match

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have two list of dictionaries. One is in the nested hierarchical format and another one is in simple list of dictionaries. I am trying to do like 'outer join' that we do in pandas or sql like 'join'. Basically, I am trying to capture the key/values from the dictionary where the key/value doens't exist in the other. Here is what I have tried.

dictionary 1:
large nested dictionaries:

```
data = [
    {'file_name': 'abc.pdf',
     'year':'2016',
      'overview': {
          'student_id': '123abc',
           'name': 'Adam Smith',
           'courses': ['Math', 'Physics'],
           }},

    {'file_name': 'def.pdf',
     'year':'2017',
      'overview': {
          'student_id': '123abc',
           'name': 'Adam Smith',
           'courses': ['Arts'],
           }}
]
```

dictionary 2:

```
mapper =[{
    'year':'2016',
    'student_id': '123abc',
    'counselor':'Matthews',
    'grades':'85'
}]
```

try/merging

```
pairs = zip(mapper,data)
```

try 1

```
[(x,y) for x, y in pairs if x['student_id'] == y['overview']['student_id']]

>> gives result:
[({'year': '2016',
   'student_id': '123abc',
   'counselor': 'Matthews',
   'grades': '85'},
  {'file_name': 'abc.pdf',
   'year': '2016',
   'overview': {'student_id': '123abc',
    'name': 'Adam Smith',
    'courses': ['Math', 'Physics']}})]
```

try 2:

```
[(x,y) for x, y in pairs if x['student_id'] == y['overview']['student_id'] & x['year'] == y['year']]
# gives errors: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'`
```

Trying to get this result: if year and student_id in both dictionary match then give this results. From dictionary 2: I am trying to match if year and student_id match then populate counselor,'grades' to dictionary 1. If the do not match, then given the dictionary element.

```
new_data = [
    {'file_name': 'abc.pdf',
     'year':'2016',
      'overview': {
          'student_id': '123abc',
           'name': 'Adam Smith',
           'courses': ['Math', 'Physics'],
            'counselor':'Matthews',
            'grades':'85'
           }},

    {'file_name': 'def.pdf',
     'year':'2017',
      'overview': {
          'student_id': '123abc',
           'name': 'Adam Smith',
           'courses': ['Arts'],
           }}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `zip` will not be a good option in this case. I would merge the ['overview'] dict of data with the mapper dict:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(data):
    for j in mapper:
        if i['overview']['student_id'] in j['student_id'] and i['year'] == j['year']:
            data[idx]['overview'] = {**i['overview'], **j}
```

Comment: @ StaticX Thanks for your solution above. I am able to execute it. However, it is still quite what I am looking for in the output above in my question. I am trying to get keys/value when both student_id and year matches from dictionary 2 to dictionary 1. In your case, it is only matching to 'student_id' but not 'year'. I tried this `i['overview']['student_id'] in j['student_id'] and i['year'] in j['year']` but didn't work

Comment: Ok @sharp I've updated it to match the year. You just needed `==` in this case since it is a single value, not a dictionary.